# Android keycode_back closes application

Tags: android, url, back, keycode

I want the back button on the android phone to act like the back button for my web browser. At present, it closes the application instead of going back to the previous screen.

I wrote this incredibly ugly hack to get around it as follows:

Stack stack=new Stack();

and every time a new webview is loaded i store it in the stack using

```
stack.push(url);

@Override     
         public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {          
             // Back?         
             if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {             
                     // Back             
                     String url = stack.pop();               
                     if(url.indexOf("index.html")>0)stack.push("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                     this.loadUrl(url);
                 }          
             // Return         
             return true;   
             }
```

Now, I really want to do it the android way but have no clue how to achieve this...

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
@Overridepublic boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {        // do something on back.        return true;    }    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```

with

```
@Overridepublic void onBackPressed() {// do something on back.return;}
```

does not work for me and I dont konw why (sad android face)

Comment: what the problem actually you getting? is onBackPressed want to call using this onKeyDown event?

Comment: I suppose that is what I want to happen. When I press the back key I want the previous screen to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private WebView webView;
```

...

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

...

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, it really didn't like that at all! I got a Force close. I have this code in a sub class of the main class. Would this be causing the problem?